# Bot - Why I can't enable logging conversations?

Tags: chat, bots, einstein-chatbot

In [Enable Einstein Bots](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bots_service_enable.htm&type=5) docs there's a step-by-step guide of how to store the conversation data.

Screenshots suggest that there should be a setting to enable this in Enstein Bots Setup:

[image]

However in my case the layout looks slighty different. There is no such setting and the only one available is for enabling Bot options menu:

[image]

I'm aware that Chatbot is quite a new feature of Salesforce and it changes frequently so the guide/screenshots may be outdated. That's why I searched for this option in other places but with no success.

Does anyone know how to enable / disable logging conversation details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Here's the answer provided by the Salesforce Support:

> Please note the settings could be enabled only if the bot is Inactive.
>
> Hence please navigate to Setup > Einstein Bot
>
> then under the list of the "My Bots" (select one bot that you want to
> change) click the down arrow and click 'Edit'.
>
> Once on the Bot builder page, at the top left corner, you will see a
> dropdown menu with the "Dialogs" (default) option.
>
> Open the dropdown and select the "Overview" page.
>
> After you deactivate the Bot, the Edit (Pencil Icon) next to the "Log
> Conversation" will be enabled and you can turn the setting on.